# Selection of Model Element or JvmType with Xtext

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

I am trying to create a dsl and don't know how to solve the following case.
It should be possible to generate a class with a undefined number of attributes. The attributes are defined like this:

```
PoJo:
    "model" name=ID "{"
        attributes += Attribute
        operations += Operation*
    "}" 
;

Attribute:
    type=AttributeType name=ID
;

AttributeType:
    SimpleType | ComplexType
;

ComplexType returns JvmType:
    PoJo | Activity
;

SimpleType:
    type = [jvmTypes::JvmType | QUALIFIED_PACKAGE]
;
```

i tried to include the PoJo Elements as JvmType so it is possible to refer to it everytime a new attribute is needed as datatype. I want to refer to PoJo or Activity or any JvmType. Does anybody know how to make this work ? Thank you all for helping

Comment: Hi,this is usually not done this way. the usual way is to inherit from xbase, map the Pojo and Activities to classes via a JvmModelInferrer and have a JvmParametrizedTypeReference as type for the reference only. have a look at the domain model example. another way would be to have a syntactic difference between a ref to a dsl element and a ref to a jvm type

Comment: thank you. i will have a look at xbase and the example project